# $2D$ Line Segment - Triangle Intersection

Tags: analytic-geometry

I've seen similar questions but could not solve my problem with those. My question is how to detect an intersection of a line segment and a triangle on a 2D coordinate system? I don't need the point of intersection, I just quickly need to decide whether the segment cuts into the triangle or not.

The Line segment is represented by two points, S (Sx,Sy).
The triangle is represented by 3 points, T (T1x,T1y,  T2x,T2y,   T3x,T3y)

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: One option: Define the line segment as $S(u)=S_0+u(S_1-S_0),0\leq u\leq1$ and a triangle edge as $T(v)=T_0+v(T_1-T_0),0\leq v\leq1$. Then the line segment and the triangle edge intersect if there exists a pair $(u,v)$ satisfying $S(u)=T(v),0\leq u,v\leq1$. This may be harder than the original problem though.

Answer (score 0):

All right, maybe we can go for an algorithm!

given the two end of the segment $A=(a_x,a_y),B=(b_x,b_y)$ and the three vertices of the triangle $C=(c_x,c_y),D=(d_x,d_y),E=(e_x,e_y)$

**Intersection** (A,B,C,D,E)

(1) **if** A is in the triangle and B is not (or vice versa) 
    **then** *return* True

(2) **if** (Intersection(A,(A+B)/2,C,D,E) **or** Intersection((A+B)/2,B,C,D,E))
    **then** *return* True **else** *return* False

Here is a method to check whether a point is in a triangle using cross product http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/

bad one (thanks Daryl):
To check if an end of the segment, say A, is in the triangle we can simply check it's coordinates against the triangle vertices ones:

For A to be in the triangle we should have
$min \{c_x,d_x,e_x\} \leq a_x \leq max \{c_x,d_x,e_x\}$ and
$min \{c_y,d_y,e_y\} \leq a_y \leq max \{c_y,d_y,e_y\}$

Comment: Your check on $A$ only ensures it is in the bounding rectangle of the triangle. It is possible that it is not in the triangle.

Comment: yes, you're right! thanks!

Comment: So the current algorithm is not correct? It is not enough for me to check the bounding rectangle of the triangle.

Comment: the issues is the way i suggested to check if the point belong to the triangle (i.e. the procedure that corresponds to "A is in the triangle and B is not") but you can use the cross product method showed in http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/